# Creating radio buttons with NgFor

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I want to use `NgFor` to create a set of radio buttons as part of a form. They appear just fine but as soon as I get `NgModel` involved it breaks so that clicking any of them always selects the last one (except the last which selects the second-to-last).

[I have set up a plunk of the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/GDosEBexlfUEnxx8He60?p=preview)

Everything seems to work fine if you remove the `ngModel` from the end of *line 12* in the template but without that my form is dead in the water. Right?

Any advice would be great. I'm a proper newb to forms and a relative newb to `NgModel`.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the attr part when binding to your input.

From this :

```
 <input type="radio" name="gameType" [attr.id]="'gameType'+i" [attr.value]="i" ngModel>
```

To this :

```
 <input type="radio" name="gameType" [id]="i" [value]="i" ngModel>
```

Here's the modified [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JaS255BXF0hj0G8EQujM?p=preview)

Comment: Great. That worked a treat. So are `id` and `value` not attributes then? Is this a prop vs attr thing?

Comment: Yes. They are native property so you don't need the attr prefix

Answer (score 0):

You could just change the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="gameType" [attr.id]="'gameType'+i" [attr.value]="i" ([ngModel])="defaultSpecs[i].model">
```

This will tell ngModel to use two way binding (banana in the box syntax added) and mutate your defaultSpecs object to include a property called model which contains a boolean which indicates if its selected or not.

Your defaultSpecs object is referenced using the repeats index as its an array.